# Querystring does not return all values

Tags: vb.net, iis-6, query-string

I've searched all over the web for an answer and I can't see anybody with the same or similar problem (which surprises me certainly, so I certainly suspect it's me somehow).

When I do a

Request.Querystring("key1")
Request.Querystring("key2")

the system doesn't seem to parse the second ?/value out but treats it as if key1 was all one string, e.g. http://www.example.com/default.aspx?key1=abc?key2=def returns abc?key2=def ...as if it completely ignores or doesn't parse out the second (or other if more) key/value pairs.

Wondering if anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one ? in your request, following separators should be &

regards

/t

Comment: And when using querystrings from hyperlinks (<a href="..), encode the & with &amp;

Answer (score 1):

don't use this

```
http://www.example.com/default.aspx?key1=abc?key2=def
```

QueryStrings start with ? however each other token is delmited by &

```
http://www.example.com/default.aspx?key1=abc&key2=def
```

This will yield the proper results when you use

```
Request.Querystring("key2")
```

Comment: Jason & User24...  thanks, my god, I've been looking at that for a couple of days driving myself nuts...doh!  a simple syntactical error of course.